# 2nd largest from 3 numbers, using if_else

Tags: c

I'm kind of new to C programming and I recently bumped into a question of finding the 2nd largest number from 3 numbers.  I tried it using if...else, but it is always giving the smallest number as output.  What is the logical error I'm making in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    a=10;
    b=30;
    c=7;
    if(a>b) {
        if(a>c) {
            if(b>c)
                printf("2nd largest is %d",c);
            else
                printf("2nd largest is %d",b);
        }
    } else

    {
        if(b>c) {
            if(c>a)
                printf("2nd largest is %d",a);
            else
                printf("2nd largest is %d",c);
        } else
            printf("2nd largest is %d",b);
    }
}
```

Comment: E.g., if `a > b` but `a <= c` you have no code to handle this case.

Comment: +1 for a nicely written first question that includes some code :-)

Comment: The first `if(a>b)` is insufficient to eliminate `a,b, or c` from being the answer.  Therefore both the true and false path must potentially print `a,b, or c`.  The posted code's `a>b` path never prints `a`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(a>b) {
    if(a>c) { //a is the greatest!
        if(b>c) // the *greater* of the two remaining is the second greatest
            printf("2nd largest is %d",c); // if b > c, output b!
        else
            printf("2nd largest is %d",b); // if c > b, output c! 
    } // I think this got missed:  What if c > a and a > b?
} else

{
    if(b>c) { //b is the greatest!
        if(c>a) //As above, the *greater* of the two remaining is what you are looking for
            printf("2nd largest is %d",a); // c is greater, so output it
        else
            printf("2nd largest is %d",c); // a is greater
    } else // c > b and b > a, this is correct.
        printf("2nd largest is %d",b);
}
```

Comment: ITs work but its totally not reusable nor maintainable, what happen if we change for 5 digit to sort instead of 3?

Comment: That would require a different strategy, but is well outside the scope of this question.  With 5 numbers, I would recommend against accomplishing it with a bunch of if-else blocks, as was the stated intent for this question.

Comment: He sais that he is new to c, to I guess that he didn have a lot of Algorithm notion as well... Sometime the good answer is not "the answer itself" Its the one that will elevate his programmer skills

Comment: Yes, and I think there is value to performing and correcting an exercise in how if, else logic works.

Comment: You right, sorry to Nit-Picking you, Its worst since I quick smoking last month hehe

Answer (score 1):

Logic is fine but need to swap the printing of the variables as below

1)

```
        if(b>c)
            printf("2nd largest is %d",b);
        else
            printf("2nd largest is %d",c);
```

2)

```
       if(c>a)
            printf("2nd largest is %d",c);
        else
            printf("2nd largest is %d",a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a>=b && a>=c) {   
    if(b>=c) printf("2nd largest is %d",b);
    else printf("2nd largest is %d",c);
} else if(b>=a && b>=c) {
    if(a>c=) printf("2nd largest is %d",a);
    else printf("2nd largest is %d",c);
} else if(c>=a && c>=b) {
    if(a>=b) printf("2nd largest is %d",a);
    else printf("2nd largest is %d",b);
}
```

or

```
 static int middleVal(int a, int b, int c) {
    if(a >= b && a >= c) return b > c? b : c;
    return middleVal(b,c,a);
    }
```

Comment: dang! should have kept that public private

Comment: +1 for an interesting recursive method.  Possible easily extensible to 4+ parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do these operations, but if you just had the binary min and max functions at your disposal:

```
printf("2nd largest is %d", min(min(max(a,b),max(b,c)),max(a,c)));
```

If you need a more generalized selection (not just the 2nd largest element, but the kth largest element) use a selection algorithm like quickselect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use qsort and array to acheive this

there is an example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// This is a custom function for qsort where we define the sort rules
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)b - *(int*)a );
}
int main() {
int n;

// Set the number of element
int values[]           = {10, 30, 7};

// Dynamically get the number of element 
int nbOfValue;
nbOfValue = sizeof(values) / sizeof(int);

// Set the number of element to display
int nbOfValueToDisplay = 2;


/*
    Will reorganize you array value 
*/
qsort(values, nbOfValue, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);


for (n = 0 ; n < nbOfValueToDisplay; n++ ) {
  printf("%d ", values[n]);
}

}
```